# type error while printing json values in to Excel.?

Tags: python, json, excel, api

I am new to python please help me on this:

I am just trying to print JSON values in to excel.

Here the code i used:

```
response1 = requests.get(url, headers=headers , verify=False)
    wb = load_workbook('testexcel.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    json_data = json.loads(response1.text)
    for row, x in enumerate(json_data):
    ws['A1'] = 'id'
    column_cell = 'A'
    ws[column_cell+str(row+2)] = (x['id'])
    ws['B1'] = 'Closed Time'
    column_cell = 'B'
    ct = x['close_time']
    c = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ct/1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    ws[column_cell+str(row+2)] = (c)
    wb.save('testexcel.xlsx')
```

Input JSON:

{"credibility":2,"source_address_ids":[65762,67784,65505,65862,67601,62030,66837,61630,63707,63242,63609,62901,65958,62553,62602,62605,62277,66363,62764,64284,63062,64765,67902,63452,65375,65741,68742,63623,64005,69415,59861,60431,65463,66352,69627,66120,60333,64430,62968,63766,61863,64693,63589,61126,70587,59288,60358,63567,61537,64115,65827,60592,65199,64586,66410,64279,68254,60359,62021,60079,65474,60697,64232,67498,61955,63639,60315,67534,65650,61116,64733,68085,70608,64509,69621,69535,66355,61629,66979,61463,65842,59948,65401,60448,59742,68792,60559,60428,61340,65320,62916,67482,69445,61804,61551,59955,59946,61524,68111,64443,65553,63130,65616,61467,61632,64255,69506,60060,59903,67721,60160,68143,65990,68689,70596,60149,61940,63762,61883,60291,61659,63393,62085,60829,61067,59225,64099,60204,66329,60004,60852,60393,66295,67473,59839,60774,60065,69543,65261,60180,59495,64300,65661,69100,68690,63382,67519,62212,61065,68991,64096,67452,64299,65390,63323,62090,64777,66431,60295,67641,64126,68832,60546,68321,60608,68174,63024,60470,64471,61183,64529,59807,59649,67741,68921,69513,60637,65440,62659,67932,62253,65469,69687,63716,60323,61933,61662,65782,65962,60378,68387,59175,60689,70598,60126,63406,65879,59467,64503,67463,60316,62222,68973,62103,60868,64451,66279,59470,59966,62787,66483,61110,59235,60207,70668,64690,62066,68896,65577,60842,63503,68700,61908,59607,64485,65473,60279,66210,66284,59693,63437,59993,62426,62076,66890,67475,61810,62729,60820,61990,66278,59585,65481,65302,69668,63302,68855,64223,59694,64403,61815,70593,69021,63000,59641,66348,68045,60553,64389,65800,60847,60253,62037,61720,60083,65441,67518,66395,67991,60145,68244,59756,65845,59638,68916,59910,67895,67889,68187,60832,63092,66878,67459,60945,62656,60150,63480,60551,66479,60899,69043,60302,63667,68388,69128,65668,67634,62616,65212,61555,66265,64349,69551,67679,63071,60790,65335,69444,60410,65789,60693,68002,67794,66191,65586,62867,60994,66390,66915,59870,62552,65246,68083,59294,61111,69675,61475,65865,61591,64088,65994,66489,65705,67616,61970,61071,66888,63725,65215,68975,62568,59490,60679,60897,66117,66054,60963,68093,62503,61617,59291,60369,64390,59496,60805,66004,68168,68407,60039,59518,60732,68020,64551,59342,65795,66926,64323,64683,69548,63637,63021,65651,59575,63449,62715,65365,67877,69108,70583,68986,60759,67468,62232,63810,60047,65720,65585,68389,68319,68744,65337,61939,65470,59488,67546,59622,65672,69039,68332,63444,61083,60070,60552,65190,60346,63481,59686,60841,62149,64854,59962,66440,69676,70580,60128,65294,63332,64302,65763,67880,59873,66304,67774,64143,59879,59168,62984,66472,60462,62508,66407,62655,64326,66371,67738],"remote_destination_count":1,"local_destination_address_ids":[],"assigned_to":"abcd","local_destination_count":0,"source_count":435,"start_time":1447320116826,"id":23159,"destination_networks":["other"],"inactive":true,"protected":true,"policy_category_count":0,"description":"Firewall Permit\n","category_count":1,"domain_id":8,"relevance":1,"device_count":1,"security_category_count":1,"flow_count":0,"event_count":6109,"offense_source":"127.0.0.1","status":"CLOSED","magnitude":0,"severity":0,"username_count":0,"closing_user":"amcd","follow_up":false,"closing_reason_id":104,"close_time":1447759629000,"source_network":"other","last_updated_time":1447327073500,"categories":["Firewall Permit"],"offense_type":1}

I am getting this below error while i trying to print:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Offence automation\API_0.3.py", line 115, in <module>
    c = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ct/1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `ct` is `None` and you try to divide it by `1000.0`.

Comment: @timgeb without dividing ct. I can not able to change epoch time to GMT time. that's why i used like that. If time is "1450195200000" i want in "1450195200". Then only i print the exact value.

Comment: You got this backwards. Without `ct` being a number you can't divide it.

Comment: I can not able to understand. But I used same method for convert `"start_time":1447320116826` value to GMT it is working properly. I am confused where i am doing wrong. Both are epoch time convert in to GMT. @timgeb

Comment: @timgeb any other ideas. How to resolve this.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

This is why because in close_time sometimes the value will be null. So we cant divide string. Then i used like this:
`

```
ws['I1'] = 'Closed Time'
    column_cell = 'I'
    #ct = x['close_time']
    #print (ct)
    if x['close_time'] == None:
        print (0)
        ws[column_cell+str(row+2)] = 'None'
    elif x['close_time'] != None:
        ct = x['close_time']
        c = (datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ct/1000.0).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
        ws[column_cell+str(row+2)] = (c)+' GMT'
        print (ct)`
```

Now working fine.

Thanks Guys.